# How to retrieve boolean value in javascript API

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I can get values from column of types string with the get API:

```
var user = Parse.User.current();
var firstName = user.get('firstName');
```

But whenever I try to get a boolean value, it's always returning true where it's sometimes false:

```
var notificationStatus =    user.get('notification');// It's always true
```

The 'notification' column in my parse class is of type Boolean. So how can I get the boolean value of a bool column?

Comment: Is it actually a boolean, or is it a string? `false != "false"`

Comment: do a console.log(user) to inspect what's there..

Comment: @Mathletics the field `notification` is of type Boolean.

Comment: @Fosco the user is debugged and it's pasting the right data, I just can extract the firstName as shown above, but I couldn't extract the bool value

Comment: @whoever_downvote_my_post can you leave a comment to explain your downvote? my post is pretty clear and nothing in the docs deals with retrieving boolean fields in the JS parse SDK.

Comment: if notification is a field on user, and it's boolean, this should work.  I asked you to console.log it so you could see the exact data... what does the console.log show for notification?  If it shows a true boolean, you should open a bug on developers.facebook.com

Comment: It shows the correct value set on Parse class, for some users it shows `true`, for some other instances it shows `false` so the data are pulled correctly and showing right values in the console. The problem is on the `get` API, it seems not parsing the boolean values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this using `Parse.User.current()`, be aware that it loads the user from the local cache, and this data might be stale.

If you change this boolean in the Dashboard/Data Browser then run your code, try adding a call to `fetch()` as follows:

UPDATE: forgot that `fetch()` is async, read the properties in the `success` block

```
var user = Parse.User.current();
// get latest copy
user.fetch({
    success: function(updatedUser) {
        // now query parameters...
        var firstName = updatedUser.get('firstName');
        var notificationStatus = updatedUser.get('notification');
    }
});
```

When you do a query this isn't needed, but the current user is cached locally so you sometimes need to force a refresh.

Comment: That's it. I forgot about the fetch API. Thanks.